# Grafana email does not have the right url when root_url is set to '%(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana'

Tags: grafana

I am setting up Grafana Smtp for email invitations.
I am using grafana helm chart and my configuration looks like this -

```
grafana.ini:
  smtp:
    enabled: true
    host: smtp.sendemail.com:587
    user: 'someuser'
    password: 'somepassword'
    from_address: join-grafana@somewhere.com
    from_name: Join Us At Grafana
  server:
    root_url: '%(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana'
    serve_from_sub_path: true
```

When I send email invitations, email has the link to http://localhost:3000/grafana/... not the domain name I have set; For every purpose, I am able to use the grafana url by domain name like - https://somedomain.com/grafana.

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually define all the variables, else they will use the default value, which is what you are seeing in your email; if you are running through a proxy server like I do, you might need to change the URL template:

```
[server]
# Protocol (http, https, h2, socket)
protocol = http

# The http port  to use
http_port = 3030

# The public facing domain name used to access grafana from a browser
domain = metrics.example.com

# The full public facing url you use in browser, used for redirects and emails
# If you use reverse proxy and sub path specify full url (with sub path)
root_url = 'https://%(domain)s/grafana/'
```

Comment: I have exposed grafana through the nginx ingress controller, that's the reason why grafana.ini have the default values except the subpath to root_url and flag serve_from_sub_path set to true. I have the grafana working perfectly except this smtp part; I think, Grafana does not see the ingress part for email, TBH it is not required to see - is there a way I can modify/customize the email content sent out?

Comment: The emails are dynamically generated based on server configuration, if you read the comments above the `root_url` line, it explicitly states that this is what is used for the emails. Works fine for me on current version (v6.5.3) Try to fully the variable: `root_url = 'https://metrics.example.com/grafana/'`

Comment: I found the place where the email content template resides but is not customizable; I assume, there would be people who has my usecase of using ingress/nginx to expose grafana and would like to have an option to  customize the email content.