# on grafana password recovery email, how to have own HTTPS domain on recovery URL?

Tags: reverse-proxy, grafana, change-password

In Grafana, after successfully setting up the email config so that my users can set their passwords (despite the scant email documentation for this, I had to follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U69YYWV7BW0), I get the following recovery email:

> Hi,
>
> Please click the following link to reset your password within **2 hours** .
>
> http://localhost:3000/user/password/reset?code=[SOME-CODE]
>
> Not working? Try copying and pasting it to your browser.

The link works well but only (obviously) if I change `localhost:3000` to my own domain.

**How can I have the `localhost:3000` string in the password recovery email be my domain?**

**How can I make sure the URL is also https?** (My server should redirect it to https, but I'd like users to see https since many would like that safety signal.)

For context, I followed this tutorial for setting up the grafana server with a reverse proxy: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-grafana-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 0):

Configure the `root_url` option in the `[server]` config section properly.

Answer (score 0):

> **How can I have the localhost:3000 string in the password recovery email be my domain?**

Changing the `domain` parameter in `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` to my domain works in not showing `localhost` anymore and directing the URL to my site.

```
domain = [my domain]
```

> **How can I make sure the URL is also https?**

What ended up working - taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60049453/) - was editing `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` as @Jan Garaj partially suggested:

```
root_url = https://%(domain)s/
```

Note that with this solution, you you have a hard-coded *https* URL without changing the `protocol` parameter, and thus you avoid running into messy certificate paths, permissions or groups. There’s also no changing nginx config files.

More context in [this thread](https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-have-own-https-domain-on-password-recovery-url/40207).